# PHP: initialization of object properties when declaring vs when instantiating

Tags: php, oop

Consider these classes:

```
class Test_A {

    protected $value;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->value = null;
    }

}

class Test_B {

    protected $value = null;

    public function __construct() {

    }

}
```

I would like to know which one is considered best practice for initializing object properties and why.

Both are syntactically correct and according to PHP manual, a property can be initialized when declared only if the value is not depending on any calculation (protected $a = a + b;). If it does depend on some calculation or runtime value, it should be initialized within the class constructor.

**Ref:** http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php (see Example #1)

Keeping that in mind, is it a good practice to always initialize properties when declaring unless they actually need to be calculated?

Comment: doesn't the last line of that paragraph answer your question?

Comment: No, I still don't know if there is any drawback I haven't considered. If it doesn't matter I want to know that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If it does depend on some calculation or runtime value, it should be
>   initialized within the class constructor.

Actually if it depends on some calculation or runtime value, it **must** be initialized by the constructor. PHP 5.6 [relaxes this restriction](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.const-scalar-exprs) so that expressions involving scalar values known at compile time will be legal initializers.

> Is it a good practice to always initialize properties when declaring
>   unless they actually need to be calculated?

Sure, as long as you have a meaningful value for them. If you don't explicitly initialize them on declaration they get implicitly set to `null`.